# Copying values from separate Excel files into separate Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have `ABC1` Excel file, from where I would like to copy column `A` values (`A1:A50`) and 
I also have `ABC2` Excel file, from where I would like to copy column `B` values (`B1:B50`).

I want to paste them into
     `XYZ1` ([`ABC1` `A1`] to `D1` and [`ABC2` `B1`] to `D2`) Excel file,
     `XYZ2` ([`ABC1` `A2`] to `D1` and [`ABC2` `B2`] to `D2`) Excel file,
     `XYZ3` ... and...
     `XYZ50`
separate Excel files.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Try recording a macro while performing those steps: that will give you a starting point which you can then try to modify.  If you run into problems then post back with that code and I'm sure you'll get some suggestions.

Comment: I was trying to record a macro but I had some problems.
 especially when I am opening a new excel file to save the solution in a seperate file I need help with the automatic generat a new file name (XYZ1, then XYZ2).

Answer (score 0):

Would look something like this

```
dim x as integer
dim wb as workbook

for x=1 to 50
    set wb=workbooks.add()
    'copy data to wb.sheets(1)
    wb.saveas filename:="C:\destination_folder\XYZ" & x & ".xlsx"
    wb.close false
next x
```